# Remove all files created by specifed user

Tags: c#, ntfs, quota

I have quotas-enabled drive and I want to remove all files created by specifed user (actually a set of applications that runs using special account) from that drive. How can I do this without recursivly checking all files and folders on HDD is it created by specifed user or not? I just need to get "iterator".

Comment: Do you mean the *file owner*?

Comment: Programmatically I believe that you'd need to iterate all the files of your driver. Maybe you could move this question do serverfault to see if guys there can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on following example

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        string user = @"Domain\UserName";
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\TestFolder")
            .Where(x => IsOwner(x, user));
        Parallel.ForEach(files, File.Delete);
    }

    private static bool IsOwner(string filePath, string user)
    {
        return string.Equals(File.GetAccessControl(filePath).GetOwner(typeof (NTAccount)).Value, user,
                             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like there is no way to get this list without iterating each file on harddrive. ok, thanks )

Answer (score 1):

In term of improving performance, I think you could use Task Parallel Library when using recursive algorithm to search file and folder.

Another way, you could do that [Lucence](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) was a useful framework for search and it was already published version for .NET

Comment: TPL and IO - not SSD? For lot of files results will be much worse than without TPL...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do that iteratively and *very* efficiently using USN Change Journal, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798.aspx. With proper use of filtering, you can get list of files created by specific user within specific time period.

On the other hand, this technique is quite complicated and is suitable for time-critical applications; if efficiency is not the focal point of your application, I'd choose simpler solution.